# What's wrong with this html5 data attribute

Tags: jquery, html

This is the anchor that MVC 2 is creating:

```
<a class="syncLink" data-resultstarget="OmsToAdminPzInfoSyncResult" 
     href="/Sync/OmsToAdminPzInfoAjax" 
     onclick="Sys.Mvc.AsyncHyperlink.handleClick(this, new Sys.UI.DomEvent(event), { insertionMode: Sys.Mvc.InsertionMode.replace, updateTargetId: &#39;OmsToAdminPzInfoSyncResult&#39; });">
Pz Info</a>
```

And here's some jQuery.  The first alert shows what it should, but the second shows undefied.  I'm using jQuery 1.4.1

```
    $("a.syncLink").click(function () {
        alert($(this).attr("data-resultstarget"));
        alert($(this).data("resultstarget"));
    });
```

I know I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602565/using-data-attributes-with-jquery) before, but I don't have any camel casing here, so I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Works for me in [jQuery 1.7](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9S4T/) but not [in jQuery 1.3.2](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9S4T/1/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This feature was added in jQuery 1.4.3.
You need to upgrade jQuery.

In older versions, you'll need to use `.attr("data-resultstarget")`

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: No; it says 1.4.3.  http://api.jquery.com/data/ `As of jQuery 1.4.3 HTML 5 data- attributes will be automatically pulled in to jQuery's data object. The treatment of attributes with embedded dashes was changed in jQuery 1.6 to conform to the W3C HTML5 specification.`

Comment: Docs say data was added in 1.2 - so that was only for local, in-memory storage—ie not reading from html5 attributes?  http://docs.jquery.com/Data

Comment: Ok - got it.  Data was extended in 1.4.3 to support html5 data attributes.  Thank you for the quick answer @SLaks.

Comment: I went and reviewed the source code for 1.4.1 just to check, and there's definitely no data-attribute logic behind-the-scenes.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade your jQuery library. This feature was added in the later version.