# How to add attributes to a HTML element in a valid way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to be able to add an attribute to a HTML element to be able to identify what its referring to.

E.g if I have a list of names and a checkbox next to each name, like this:

```
<div id="users">
 Bob smith <input type=checkbox />
</div>
```

And when a checkbox is clicked and the event handler function for it is called, I want to be able to identify which user was selected/unselected.

Ideally I'm looking for something like this:

```
<input type=checkbox data-userId = "xxx" />
```

Then when its clicked:

```
function handleClick()
{
  var userId = $(this).attr('data-userId');
}
```

However I'm looking to do this in a way that won't break my HTML validation, and would still be valid HTML and work in all browsers.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding data- attributes to your dom elements and then reading them with

```
var userId = $(this).attr('data-userId');
```

or even

```
var userId = $(this).data('userId');
```

**IS** the correct way to do this, and will *not* break any HTML validation.

Just note that there will be some case manipulation performed by jQuery on your data- attribute, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7602630/352552).  To keep things simple, consider changing `data-userId` to `data-userid`

Comment: It's perfectly valid in HTML5, nothing earlier

Answer (score 6):

[**Data attributes**](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) are provided by html5 and are valid attributes. You can access data attributes by data method by jquery

```
var userId = $(this).data('userId');
```