# Accessing a value from a jQuery object created from .data()

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, javascript-objects, custom-data-attribute

I've got several HTML elements with various data-attributes. **I'm trying to use jQuery to store all of the data attributes for a particular element when it's clicked, then insert one of the values from that Object into another element as text.** I've tried various approaches I've seen on SO, and I think I'm properly storing the data, but I can't figure out a straightforward way to pull out a particular `data-attribute` value so I can insert it in the `#display` element. The HTML:

```
<span class="source" data-spanName="spanOne" data-spanPosition="first">Span One</span>
<span class="source" data-spanName="spanTwo" data-spanPosition="second">Span Two</span>
<span class="source" data-spanName="spanThree" data-spanPosition="third">Span Three</span>

<span id="display">display attribute here</span>
```

The jQuery I've tried:

Attempt 1 (returns [object Object]):

```
$('.source').click(function () {
    var rowData = $( this ).data();
    $('#display').text( rowData ); //returns [object Object]
});
```

Attempt 2 (returns undefined):

```
$('.source').click(function () {
    var rowData = $( this ).data();
    $('#display').text( $.rowData[0].spanname ); //returns undefined
});
```

Attempt 3 (displays all data, but as a string):

```
$('.source').click(function () {
    var rowData = $( this ).data();
    var prettyRowData = JSON.stringify( rowData );
    $('#display').text( prettyRowData ); //returns attributes, but as a string and I'd have to parse it to pull out a value 
});
```

Desired end result:

```
<span id="display">spanOne</span>
```

Comment: Why did you try [0] when you clearly aren't storing any kind of array?

Comment: you simply need to do rowdata.<attributenamewithout data- in all lowercase>, as suggested in the documentation.

Comment: I think part of my confusion was from reading the docs for `jQuery.data()` rather than `.data()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The naming conventions for data attributes are explained pretty well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602565/using-data-attributes-with-jquery)

But your second attempt seems really close. However, you're accessing an object as if it's an Array, so you'll need to try a different way to access it:

```
$('.source').click(function () {
    var rowData = $( this ).data();

    // proper way to get the data
    var spanName = rowData.spanname;
    $('#display').text( spanName ); 

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
name = $(this).attr('data-spanName');
pos = $(this).attr('data-spanPosition');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.source').click(function(){
    var text = $(this).data('spanName');
    $('#display').text(text);
});
```